# How to get the corresponding id of a max field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I am still new to mysql commands and I learned how to get the max value of a column and count of a column. My database is named db and my table (named "foo") looks like this:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| expires  | datetime    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| extra    | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| valid    | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| trust_id | varchar(64) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| user_id  | varchar(64) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Basically, I want to know if there is a way to get the max date of the expires field and then print out the corresponding fields like user_id and id. So far this is the command I currently use to get the max date from expires in the command line

```
mysql -u root db -e "select max(id) from foo;"
```

this alone will give me:

```
+---------------------+
| max(expires)        |
+---------------------+
| 2016-08-05 17:54:44 |
+---------------------+
```

What I would like to do is get this back:

```
+---------------------+--------+--------+
| max(expires)        | id     | user_id|
+---------------------+--------+--------+
| 2016-08-05 17:54:44 |cd97eb4 | 2bf2cec|
+---------------------+--------+--------+
```

So then I would have the max expiration date along with the id and user id for that expiration date.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying you want the max expires by id?

Comment: You need to make the max query a subquery and join it back to the original table on the max value against the field it was calculated from; keeping in mind you may get multiple rows in the results if more than one row had the max value.

Comment: @MattCremeens made update to the post. I hope the question is clearer :)

Comment: @zet I've made an addendum to my answer in response to your edit, which did help to clear things up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the `id` and `user_id` corresponding to that (max) date, then something like this should do

```
select expires, id, user_id
from foo
where expires in
    (select max(expires) 
     from foo)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the clear and excellent solution!

Comment: Good to hear. I'm glad you found this solution intuitive and easy to understand. I feel that is worth something.

Answer (score 2):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select f.*
from foo f
order by f.expires desc
limit 1;
```

I think this is the simplest way.  And with an index on `foo(expires)`, it should have the best performance as well.